# Effectively notify when MySQL data entry changes

Tags: php, mysql, notify

I've been using an HTTP POST to a php file to change entries in a given MySQL database. Essentially, the second the value changes, I would like the user that is viewing the database table to be notified. For now my temporary solution is to auto refresh a page displaying the table to keep it updated but I feel like there has to be a more efficient way of going about this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you really have to update it in the same second? It looks like a server killer feature.
Read about [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), maybe it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC mysql_affected_rows() will only report instances where the data has changed (i.e. if you try to update a row to its current values then it won't give an error).

I find it hard to believe that you've got someone watching a screen waiting for an update to occur - maybe a better approach would be to add a timestamp field to the record - but note that if you do this, and in the absence of other checks, the record will always update - to prevent make sure at least one of the fields has changed in the update.

C.

Comment: Without trying to be too specific, I want a user who has access to one particular data entry to be alerted or notified the instant a given value changes.

Comment: Then look for a solution where you can describe what records have changed and **not** been notified

Answer (score 0):

When I had to do this, I created a one-row table containing the last time any relevant part of the database was updated. Then the once-per-second activity was confined to seeing if the contents of that one-row table showed newer than the local value; if so, refresh.

The one-row table could be updated via triggers from any table containing relevant facts, or from the application, as you think best.

Answer (score 0):

checkout [pines notify](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pnotify) i use it with ajax submitted changes

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: thanks for your input and not sure why you only put this on my link. aside from that generally speaking the links are typically made invalid. in my experience especially with big sities like jquery.com you are redirected or give a link to the new location. I'll see if i can cobble a quick example for you anyhow

Answer (score 0):

We use incrontab and curl for monitoring database table files, like /var/lib/mysql/database/table.MYD, and fire a http request to the client servers on IN_MODIFY. Works very well.