# Sending a notification when a MySql database entry changes

Tags: php, mysql, notify

I've written a php file that changes a MySql table entry when it receives an http post. I would also like the php file to send out a notification to the table entry's owner. This idea is similar to a chat room or instant messengering program. I've looked at php chat scripts but I really need something that has a very simple interface that is customizable. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What kind of notification? Mail? Instant Messenger - if so, which one? Why does a notification tool need an interface - do you want to show this on a web page?

Comment: Also, you have what is effectively the same question open on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131326/effectively-notify-when-mysql-data-entry-changes It's as hazy as this one, but has some good feedback that deserves attention.

Comment: I want to it be similar to an instant message but I do not want to use a commercial instant messengering service. Once a data entry changes, I would like some alarm to go off to a user connected to the chat session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to synchronize a set of clients, do you?

If so, look at the Long Polling technique. It's quite simple: The client opens a connection but the server does not respond until data is updated.

On the downside this won't work well with PHP. You will need to sleep() several connections, therefore blocking PHP processes.

If you have the possibility I would recommend using node.js to do stuff like that. Long Polling Chats are quire simple to implement using node ;)

Comment: I've already implemented a Comet-like pattern to do this. However, I feel the technique is too bandwidth intensive. A php chat client is far less expensive on bandwidth usage.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a named look for event triggerning and a jabber bot (extensions exist for several languages).

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/08/29/how-to-notify-event-listeners-in-mysql/